# DirectX/C++ How to Dereference Vector Data Array to Initialize D3D11 SUBRESOURCE DATA

Tags: c++, c++11, directx, directx-11

I am trying to pass a pointer to an array of Vertex Data, (base class member) into a method used to initialize the Direct3D Vertex Buffer, (ID3D11Buffer).

I want to use the variable, "v4", the pointer to the array, but I think I am not dereferencing the pointer correctly.  Could someone point me in the right direction?

I have tried many ways to make this assignment, but I can only get a basic array work, (sometimes I end up with casting to "const void *" errors).

How would I use a pointer?

The line I am having issue with is ...
vertexSubResourceData.pSysMem = v1;

(p.s. Using the V.S. C++ Nov 2012 CTP compiler .. not released yet ..)

***Answered:  Have confirmed that it is a Visual Studio 2012 C++ Nov. CTP Compiler Bug.  Arrays of Vector structures declared, even outside of the class, using C++ 11 initialization syntax are being interpreted incorrectly, (unless of course I am using the incorrect array initialization syntax).  Also Note:  This only pertains to initialization lists associated with pointers. ***

Thanks!

// Simplified Code

```
void Triangle::InitializeVertexBuffer()
{
    struct V
    {
        float X, Y, Z;    // vertex position
    };

    // Compiles But doesn't work as desired.
    // changed from V* v4 = new V[] // Compiled without range.
    // Pointer to this data would ideally come from base static pointer, or file.
    V* v4 = new V[3]     
    {
        { 0.50f, 0.5f, 0.0f },
        { 0.50f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
        { -0.50f, -0.5f, 0.0f },
    };

    // Compiles and Works to prove compiler issue with initialization lists. 
    V* vectorList = new V[3];
    vectorList[0].X = 0.5f;
    vectorList[0].Y = 0.5f;
    vectorList[0].Z = 0.00f;

    vectorList[1].X = 0.5f;
    vectorList[1].Y = -0.5f;
    vectorList[1].Z = 0.00f;

    vectorList[2].X = -0.5f;
    vectorList[2].Y = -0.5f;
    vectorList[2].Z = 0.00f;


    unsigned int size = sizeof(V) * 3; //sizeof(* Model::Vertices);

    // The Description of the Vertex Buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDescription = {0};
    vertexBufferDescription.ByteWidth = size;
    vertexBufferDescription.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER; 

    // Model Data to be transferred to GPU Buffer.

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexSubResourceData = {0};
    vertexSubResourceData.SysMemPitch = 0;
    vertexSubResourceData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    // Can't figure out how to dereference v4

    vertexSubResourceData.pSysMem = vectorList; // works, but using "v4" doesn't.

    // vertexSubResourceData.pSysMem = Model::Vertices; 
    // This is what I /really/ want .. Pointer to vertice array data from base class


    NS::DeviceManager::Device->CreateBuffer(
        &vertexBufferDescription, 
        &vertexSubResourceData, 
        &NS::ModelRenderer::VertexBuffer);
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised `V* v4 = new V[]{...}` syntax compiles in visual studio. Does that even compile?

Comment: @JesseGood  Yeah, it compiles... I am using the November CTP of VS 2012 C++ compiler with new C++ features....  I should probably mention that in the post. :)  How would you write that then?

Comment: To get that to compile with gcc 4.7.2, I had to specify the size of the array `V* v4 = new V[3]{...}`, so I don't think that is valid C++ syntax.

Comment: @JesseGood  I updated the code and added the range as you suggested... It still doesn't work as expected.  I am still thinking I am having issues dereferencing that local pointer. :(  Is there another syntax I could attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `V* v4 = new V[]{...};` it is illegal C++. The CTP compiler is accepting malformed code. Try `V* v4 = new V[3]{...};`

Checking the C++ standard, from 5.3.4p1:

> [ expression ] attribute-specifier-seqopt

So, it looks like an expression is *required* in the `[]`. I believe `new V[]` is an extension for compilers (still checking into this).

And as ildjarn points out, you want `vertexSubResourceData.pSysMem = v4;` as `&4` would you give you the address of the pointer, not the array.

**Update**

I think this is a bug in the compiler. Try the old C++03 syntax: `V* v4 = new V[3]; v4[0] = ...;` and if that works, then it definitely is a bug.

Comment: And then to answer the direct question, use `vertexSubResourceData.pSysMem = v4;` rather than `&v4`.

Comment: Not that I disagree with the conclusion, but is there a place in the spec that you can cite this for?

Comment: @JesseGood: Small point: the last `[]` in the new expression is allowed to be a non-constant expression (as stated in the line just above the one you quoted). Every `[]` other than the last must be a constant expression. But the ultimate point is that there must be an *expression* there of some kind.

Comment: @JesseGood ... fixed the syntax... still not working.  Thanks!

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks for the correction. It wouldn't make sense if a constant-expression is required there since we are talking about dynamic initialization...

Comment: @WindAndFlame : You'll have to post the actual compiler error then, as there's no reason that shouldn't work.

Comment: @ildjarn There is no compiler error.  Is there a way to copy from the Heap version of this data to the Stack version? to test this?

Comment: @WindAndFlame : Then it seems the syntax error you initially had has derailed this whole question. ;-] In any case, you shouldn't be using heap allocations here at all – the syntax you're using for `v1` is fine.

Comment: @WindAndFlame: I suspect it is a bug (CTP has a lot of bugs). Try C++03 syntax `V* v4 = new V[3]; v4[0] = ...;` and if that works, then we can be sure it is a bug.

Comment: @ildjarn   The syntax issue was only raised and clarified while troubleshooting the dereferencing issue, and the API.  The initializer list is just a place holder as in actuality, vertices are read from files or autogenerated.  I need to dump the data pointed to for SubResourceData ...  The initialization lists here are simply to demonstrate that I am having issues /locally, in method/ with dereferencing and the DirectX API.

Comment: @JesseGood Could you elaborate on that a little?  how would I aggregate those together in the 03 syntax? NM.  I I see what you are saying.

Comment: @WindAndFlame : As far as I can tell, there is no problem with dereferencing – this is merely a problem with using the DirectX API correctly (on which I am no expert).